# iOS Safari "Add to home screen" issue

Tags: ios, symfony, session, web-applications, safari

I have a web app, using this metas:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

This app is a web based php Silex/Symfony, with a login session on start.

I have my icon on my iPad, but every time i open my app, **safari reload always the login page**, even if i was logged before.

Can anyone help me on this?

```
// Register routes
$app->get('/', 'index.controller:indexAction')->bind('index')->value('require_authentication', true);
$app->get('/login', 'auth.controller:loginAction')->bind('login');
$app->get('/logout', 'auth.controller:logoutAction')->bind('logout');
$app->post('/auth', 'auth.controller:authAction')->bind('auth');
....


//before stack - check for user login, if not throw AccessDeniedHttpException
$app->before(function(Request $request, Application $app) {

    if ($app['request']->get('require_authentication')) {
        if (null === $user = $app['session']->get('user')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException("require auth");
        }else{ 
            $app["twig"]->addGlobal("user", $user);

        }
    }
});
```

This web app will be used only on iPad so no need identified code per device.

Comment: You need to provide us with more information. Put here your routing table. Also put here all code related to identifying device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route for `/` will catch all requests so you need to [reorder them such that more specific route paths are not caught be less specific ones](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html):

> The order in which the routes are defined is significant. The first matching route will be used, so place more generic routes at the bottom.

This means that your code should look like this:

```
// Register Routes
$app->get('/login', 'auth.controller:loginAction')->bind('login');
$app->get('/logout', 'auth.controller:logoutAction')->bind('logout');
$app->post('/auth', 'auth.controller:authAction')->bind('auth');
$app->get('/', 'index.controller:indexAction')->bind('index')->value('require_authentication', true);
```